# What are Scranton Reality Anchors? How do they work?

Tags: scp-foundation

Multiple SCPs (most notably [SCP-2000](http://www.scp-wiki.net/scp-2000) and now [SCP-3001](http://www.scp-wiki.net/scp-3001)) make use of something called a Scranton Reality Anchor.

However, I have (as of yet) been unable to find any information regarding the SRA other than the fact that it blocks reality-bending SCPs from doing their thing/breaking containment/whatever else SCPs like to do during their free time.

Besides the basic information given above, is there any more information as to what makes a Scranton Reality Anchor and how it works? For example, is there any technical documentation (preferably "canonical"* to the Foundation universe) that explains what they do?

<sup>* Used in this case to mean mentioned in a mainline SCP instead of a tale or similar</sup>

Comment: There is no such thing as canon in that universe. Each of the stories is a self-contained fanwork. Some *refer* to earlier stories, but there's  no overriding rules regarding the tech (or even limits on the SCP inhabitants).

Comment: Scranton! (Whaaat?) The Electric City! They call it that because of the electri-city!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Valorum is correct in that SCP does not have a set canon most of the authors agree on certain broad facts when they refer to some of the same items and the reality anchors are one such item but the only real agreement is that they anchor reality somehow

However SCPs themselves are usually only going to mention the item without explaining it the SCP format is not for exposition on the technology the foundation uses its about what an object is/does and how it is contained

[this is contained in a J SCP](http://scp-wiki.wdfiles.com/local--files/scp-1472-j/mpsra_small.png)

Its a blueprint, that is technically technical :D

Answer (score 3):

Well, Scranton Reality Anchors (SRA’s) are typically constructed from the dead remains of a reality bender, according to [S.C.P.-4231](http://www.scp-wiki.net/scp-4231) (The Montauk house) however as previously stated there is no set cannon in the SCP universe and it should be treated thusly.

Comment: Can you offer some quotes to back up your answer?

Answer (score 0):

There is mention of the structure and function of SRAs also within the [SCP-2000](https://scp-wiki.wikidot.com/scp-2000) file:

> The invention of the Scranton Reality Anchor (SRA) appears to pre-date the first activation of SCP-2000, and is credited to Dr. Robert Scranton in 1889. The main body and much of the circuitry of the SRA are constructed of a corrosion-resistant beryllium bronze alloy. Inspired by artifacts recovered [DATA EXPUNGED], effectively eliminating the appearance of virtual particle/anti-particle pairs required for Type Green reality bending phenomena to manifest. Due to the expense involved in producing the beryllium bronze alloy required for the SRA’s construction, Foundation-wide implementation of the device has been limited to units capable of an area of effect less than two cubic meters